# I bummed in to another problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, flutter-layout

After I fixed CheckBoxListTile, I copied and pasted 3 of the CheckBoxListTile under a container in Column. My problem is when I click to check on either one of them, all 3 clicks simultaneously.

How do I fix this issue so that each CheckBoxListTile would be clicked individually?

Here's the screenshot to demonstrate my problem

[image]

This is my sample code below

```
Container( 
             height: 150.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 8, left: 8),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: const Text('Cash'),
                        value: timeDilation != 0.5,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeDilation = value! ? 1.0 : 0.5;
                          });
                        },
                        secondary: const Icon(Icons.money),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                          title: const Text('Credit'),
                          value: timeDilation != 0.5,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              timeDilation = value! ? 1.0 : 0.5;
                            });
                          },
                          secondary:
                              const Icon(Icons.money_off_csred_outlined)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: const Text('Card'),
                        value: timeDilation != 0.5,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeDilation = value! ? 1.0 : 0.5;
                          });
                        },
                        secondary: const Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing same logic for all checkBox

```dart
value: timeDilation != 0.5,
onChanged: (bool? value) {
  setState(() {
    timeDilation = value! ? 1.0 : 0.5;
  });
},
```

That's why it is responding the same.It would be nice if you practice enum on this case.

```dart
enum MyOption {
  cash,
  credit,
  card,
}

class _ASGState extends State<ASG> {
  MyOption? selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
              height: 150.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 8, left: 8),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: const Text('Cash'),
                        value: selected == MyOption.cash,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selected = MyOption.cash;
                          });
                        },
                        secondary: const Icon(Icons.money),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                          title: const Text('Credit'),
                          value: selected == MyOption.credit,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selected = MyOption.credit;
                            });
                          },
                          secondary:
                              const Icon(Icons.money_off_csred_outlined)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 240, 243),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: const Text('Card'),
                        value: selected == MyOption.card,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selected = MyOption.card;
                          });
                        },
                        secondary: const Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find more about [`CheckboxListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

```dart
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            unselectedWidgetColor: colors.white,
    ),
    child: CheckboxListTile()
...
)
```

just wrap your `CheckBoxListTile` with this theme